# cannot access a disposed object mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When attempting to connect to a database requiring SSL, but SSL set to 'No' in WorkBench, I pressed cancel on the "Opening SQL Editor" and it presented me with the error:

"Cannot access a disposed object
Object name: 'HUDForm'."

Answer (score 6):

Press **Windows** + **R**
type **%appdata%**
find **MySQL**  folder
and **DELETE** that folder.

Open Workbench again and it will be fixed.

Comment: It removes all existing connections in the workbench FYI.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. I created another connection with the same IP and port number but different instance name and it worked to open the Workbench.

Give a try!

Comment: This seems to have worked for me as well, although I don't understand why.  I was using MySQL 8.0.22 on Windows 10.  The [MySQL bugs report site](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100406) suggests this has been a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above and for whatever reason had no success.

A fresh install of workbench for me worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> **It may happen if you have changed MySQL password.**

- To solve this issue, go to ***edit connection*** and **test using password**
  then load it on workbench.

Answer (score 0):

I was connecting node js and mysql, and this error message shows up when i tried to connect to mysql through workbench! the problem was that i opened my connection with node js and i didn't close it. When i closed my vscode, this error message was gone...